# Is it proper to use "a drop" in such a manner?

Tags: phrases, expressions, word-usage, phrase-usage

I recently had a discussion with a colleague regarding the phrase "a drop". We came up with the following two examples:

> Can we change the meeting to **a drop** later?
>   Can you move the tab **a drop** over?

I thought the questions sounded okay, yet my colleague had never heard of the phrase used in such a manner.

In the two example, "a drop" is basically used as a substitute for "a little" or "a bit". It may not be the best word choice, yet is it okay to use "a drop" in such a manner?

Are these sentences grammatical? Is this kind of usage of "a drop" considered slang?

Comment: It would be understandable, but it's not an expression I've ever heard. I would think it strange, or playful.

Comment: Define "*valid expression*".

Comment: @Drew I wasn't sure how to phrase my question in a way that will get my point across. I basically want to know if it is acceptable to use "a drop" like I used it in the two example questions. I'm not saying "a drop" is the best word choice, but I want to know if the two sentences are considered proper English. Do you have any suggestions on how I can rephrase my question?

Comment: Define *acceptable*. To whom, in what context? Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Drew I updated my question. Please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: @TotZam The use of *a drop* in your sentences is not idiomatic, meaning native speakers do not use the word in this way in everyday English. Going further, a *drop* refers to a liquid, so unless meetings or tabs can be talked about as liquids, I don't see how anyone would use *drop* in that manner. What is idiomatic is something like *You have a drop of chocolate on your shirt collar.* Or if you are comparing paints and have actual drops of paint that are *a drop over* from another: can we put the red paint three drops over from the green?

Comment: @Clare When you say "a drop of chocolate", you mean "a small amount of chocolate". When you say "move the tab over a drop", you mean "move the tab over a small amount". How are these different? I don't see why only one is considered idiomatic. Is it because chocolate can technically be melted to a liquid form?

Comment: I was thinking of chocolate sauce, so, yeah, it's already a liquid and referring to a literal, actual *drop* of chocolate sauce.

Comment: See @J. Taylor's comment after his answer. If you ask whether your sentences are grammatical or are clear to native English speakers, OK. But if you ask whether they are "*acceptable*", "*proper*", etc. then your question is essentially opinion-based. There is no authority that decides what is acceptable English.

Comment: @Drew I changed it to "Are these sentences grammatical?". Is my question okay now? Thanks for pointing out how it can be improved.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That makes it easier on people who try to help you, and it can help avoid opinion-based responses that are not too helpful. However, the answer might not help you as much as you would like: yes, the sentences are grammatical. (There are lots of sentences that are grammatical but do not say much or are essentially meaningless.) I think you want to (1) say what meaning you are trying to express and then (2) ask whether your sentences convey that meaning well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the usage is grammatical, and in my opinion most listeners would understand (maybe from pure context) what you mean. That is quite a low bar. In my experience this usage is not slang; I have heard it extremely rarely, if at all. Note, you would also be fighting an alternative meaning of "drop over", which is "to stop by for a short time".

I am not being critical of your question, and even up-voted it. Personally I would feel that the problems encountered in the phrase's use would be a drop over what I would be willing to face.

I decided to ask Mr. Ngram what he thought on the matter:

[image: Ngram: a smidge over, a drop over, a hair over]
[interactive Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20drop%20over%2Ca%20smidge%20over%2Ca%20hair%20over&year_start=1820&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20drop%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20smidge%20over%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20hair%20over%3B%2Cc0)

I chose three like expressions.  I took out "a bit over" because it dwarfed the other three. The normative expression, "slightly over" greatly exceeded even that.  The one thing that surprised me about this graph is that I had thought "a smidge over" had a quaint air, as if it were an old-time expression.  Apparently not.

Comment: The graph is definitely interesting. I've never heard the phrase "a hair over" used, but apparently it is gaining popularity. And I like the usage of "a drop over" in your second paragraph :)

Comment: Clicking through to the Ngram quotes in context, I found examples like "Spreading of a drop over a liquid". This is different from the way that the OP would like to use the term.

Comment: @Lawrence Ah! That probably explains why it shows up so much more often than "a smidge over". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use "drop".
Better might be:

> Can we change the meeting to a bit later?
>
> Can you move the tab a hair over?

One should be sure of the expression before using it. Sometimes using an expression that isn't common can add interest to writing or speaking. But it should be a sparing use. This was a good question to ask.

Comment: I'm not asking if it is the best word choice. What I want to know is if it is considered acceptable.

Comment: That I would not use it makes me think it should not be used.. There is a fundamental problem with "acceptable"-there is no final authority.  I did not write that you should not use the term "drop" in the contexts you supplied. It is not usual usage, so  its acceptance might depend on how it is taken by the reader or listener. I gave the answer I could give as the best advice I had.. I think it was a good question, but such questions often do not have obvious answers..

Comment: I think it's only acceptable when you're talking about liquids or feelings/sentiment. eg. "dripping with sarcasm" makes sense or "try to have just a drop of [optimism|self-respect|decency]" etc.